# String and Binary data would be truncated in Laravel db:seed

Tags: sql-server, laravel-4, migration, doctrine-migrations

I have a problem where the generated seed for SQL Server 2012 outputs this error

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
 SQLSTATE[22001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Stri
 ng or binary data would be truncated. (SQL: insert into [books] ([judul], [
 pengarang], [dcc_code], [penerbit], [isbn], [tahun], [updated_at], [created
 _at]) values (Problem solving with the programmable calculator : puzzle, ga
 mes & simulation with math & science application, David L. Dunlop  Thomas F
 . Sigmund, 510.285, Prentice Hall, 0574213201, 1983, 2015-01-26 03:30:19.00
 0, 2015-01-26 03:30:19.000))'
```

Even though I've made sure I set my schema to contain the data correctly

```
    Schema::create('books', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->engine="INNODB";
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('judul');
        $table->string('pengarang', 200);
        $table->string('dcc_code', 20);
        $table->string('penerbit', 100);
        $table->string('edisi', 100)->nullable();
        $table->string('tahun', 10);
        $table->string('isbn', 100)->nullable();
        $table->string('book_image_name', 200)->nullable();

        //Unique to Perpustakaan
        $table->string('call_number', 100)->nullable();
        $table->float('rating_cache')->default('0');
        $table->integer('rating_count')->default('0');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Here's the seed

```
    Book::create( 
        array(
            'judul' => "Problem solving with the programmable calculator : puzzle, games & simulation with math & science application",
            'pengarang' => "David L. Dunlop  Thomas F. Sigmund",
            'dcc_code' => "510.285",
            'penerbit' => "Prentice Hall",
            'isbn' => "0574213201",
            'tahun' => "1983"
        )
    );
```

Any help or hint would be appreciated! :)

Per @patricus hint, I found out that the generated column in SQL Server is only nvarchar(100) rather than nvarchar(300). Even though I've changed the type into `longText` in migrations, the generated column still is `nvarchar(100)`

Comment: Are you sure that is the right migration?  It has the line `$table->engine="INNODB";` which is specific to MySQL, not SQL Server.  Can you show the actual field definitions? Do they line up with the migration file provided?

Comment: $table->engine = "INNODB" will do nothing when being exposed on SQL Server... So the migration works.
The current solution was to deploy on MySQL which (fortunately) doesn't have the recurring problem

Comment: @patricus I just realized that the generated column is nvarchar (100) character length. It's funny consider I put 200 on the string length. Thanks for the lead! :)

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the datatype mapping of whatever client you're using. There is no such thing as a "string" data type in SQL Server nor is there such as thing as "long text". Please double check the compatibility of the client you're using to develop this, for SQL Server.